# Android ListView with onClick items

Tags: android, listview, methods, android-activity, element

I'm a new programmer and new in Android. I'm using this example http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/ and it works great.

Now I want to make the items (Dell, Samsung Galaxy S3, etc) to call a function to open a new activity with different information each.

For example:

If I touch Dell, a new Activity has to show up showing me information about Dell. If I touch Samsung, the same thing.

I Googled but couldn't find anything helpfull, any hint? I think this is basic, but I'm new so I don't really know where to start

Answer (score 81, accepted):

In your activity, where you defined your listview

you write

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){   
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?>adapter,View v, int position){
        ItemClicked item = adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);

        Intent intent = new Intent(Activity.this,destinationActivity.class);
        //based on item add info to intent
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

in your adapter's getItem you write

```
public ItemClicked getItem(int position){
    return items.get(position);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), DiscussAddValu.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

Comment: This answer turned up in the low quality review queue, presumably because you don't provide any explanation of the code. If this code answers the question, consider adding adding some text explaining the code in your answer. This way, you are far more likely to get more upvotes — and help the questioner learn something new.

Answer (score 5):

You start new activities with intents.  One method to send data to an intent is to pass a class that implements parcelable in the intent.  Take note you are passing a copy of the class.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html

Here I have an onItemClick.  I create intent and putExtra an entire class into the intent.  The class I'm sending has implemented parcelable.  Tip:  You only need implement the parseable over what is minimally needed to re-create the class.  Ie maybe a filename or something simple like a string something that a constructor can use to create the class.  The new activity can later getExtras and it is essentially creating a copy of the class with its constructor method.

Here I launch the kmlreader class of [my app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gosylvester.bestrides) when I recieve an onclick in the listview.

Note: below summary is a list of the class that I am passing so get(position) returns the class infact it is the same list that populates the listview

```
List<KmlSummary> summary = null;
...

public final static String EXTRA_KMLSUMMARY = "com.gosylvester.bestrides.util.KmlSummary";

...

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    lastshownitem = position;
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, KmlReader.class);
    intent.putExtra(ImageTextListViewActivity.EXTRA_KMLSUMMARY,
            summary.get(position));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

later in the new activity I pull out the parseable class with

```
kmlSummary = intent.getExtras().getParcelable(
                ImageTextListViewActivity.EXTRA_KMLSUMMARY);

//note:
//KmlSummary implements parcelable.
//there is a constructor method for parcel in
// and a overridden writetoparcel method
// these are really easy to setup.

public KmlSummary(Parcel in) {
    this._id = in.readInt();
    this._description = in.readString();
    this._name = in.readString();
    this.set_bounds(in.readDouble(), in.readDouble(), in.readDouble(),
    in.readDouble());
    this._resrawid = in.readInt();
    this._resdrawableid = in.readInt();
     this._pathstring = in.readString();
    String s = in.readString();
    this.set_isThumbCreated(Boolean.parseBoolean(s));
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel arg0, int arg1) {
    arg0.writeInt(this._id);
    arg0.writeString(this._description);
    arg0.writeString(this._name);
    arg0.writeDouble(this.get_bounds().southwest.latitude);
    arg0.writeDouble(this.get_bounds().southwest.longitude);
    arg0.writeDouble(this.get_bounds().northeast.latitude);
    arg0.writeDouble(this.get_bounds().northeast.longitude);
    arg0.writeInt(this._resrawid);
    arg0.writeInt(this._resdrawableid);
    arg0.writeString(this.get_pathstring());
    String s = Boolean.toString(this.isThumbCreated());
    arg0.writeString(s);
}
```

Good Luck
Danny117

Answer (score 4):

You should definitely extend you `ArrayListAdapter` and implement this in your `getView()` method. The second parameter (a `View`) should be inflated if it's value is `null`, take advantage of it and set it an `onClickListener()` just after inflating.

Suposing it's called your second `getView()`'s parameter is called `convertView`:

```
convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(final View v) {
    if (isSamsung) {
      final Intent intent = new Intent(this, SamsungInfo.class);
      startActivity(intent);
    }
    else if (...) {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

If you want some info on how to extend `ArrayListAdapter`, I recommend this [link](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-listview-with-adapter-example.html).

Answer (score 4):

well in your `onitemClick` you will send the selected value like `deal`  , and send it in your intent when opening new activity and in your new activity get the sent data and related to selected item will display your data

to get the name from the `list`

```
String item = yourData.get(position).getName();
```

to set data in intent

```
intent.putExtra("Key", item);
```

to get the data in second activity

```
getIntent().getExtras().getString("Key")
```

Answer (score 1):

**for what kind of Hell implementing Parcelable ?**

he is passing to adapter  String[] so

- get item(String) at position
- create intent
- put it as extra
- start activity
- in activity get extra

to store product list you can use here HashMap 
(for example as STATIC object)

example class describing product:

```
public class Product {
    private String _name;
    private String _description;
    private int _id

    public Product(String name, String description,int id) {
        _name = name;
        _desctription = description;
        _id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return _name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return _description;
    }
}

Product dell = new Product("dell","this is dell",1);

HashMap<String,Product> _hashMap = new HashMap<>();
_hashMap.put(dell.getName(),dell);
```

then u pass to adapter set of keys as:

```
String[] productNames =  _hashMap.keySet().toArray(new String[_hashMap.size()]);
```

when in adapter u return view u set listener like this for example:

```
 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

     Context context = parent.getContext(); 

     String itemName = getItem(position)

     someView.setOnClikListener(new MyOnClickListener(context, itemName));

 }


 private class MyOnClickListener implements View.OnClickListener { 

     private  String _itemName; 
     private  Context _context

     public MyOnClickListener(Context context, String itemName) {
         _context = context;
         _itemName = itemName; 
     }

     @Override 
     public void onClick(View view) {
         //------listener onClick example method body ------
         Intent intent = new Intent(_context, SomeClassToHandleData.class);
         intent.putExtra(key_to_product_name,_itemName);
         _context.startActivity(intent);
     }
 }
```

then in other activity:

```
@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle) {

    String productName = getIntent().getExtra(key_to_product_name);
    Product product = _hashMap.get(productName);

}
```

*key_to_product_name is a public static String to serve as key for extra

ps. sorry for typo i was in hurry :) 
ps2. this shoud give you a idea how to do it 
ps3. when i will have more time i I'll add a detailed description

**MY COMMENT:**

- **DO NOT USE ANY SWITCH STATEMENT**
- **DO NOT CREATE SEPARATE ACTIVITIES FOR EACH PRODUCT ( U NEED ONLY ONE)**

Answer (score 1):

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

//setting onclick to items in the listview.

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?>adapter,View v, int position){
Intent intent;
switch(position){

// case 0 is the first item in the listView.

  case 0:
    intent = new Intent(Activity.this,firstActivity.class);
    break;
//case 1 is the second item in the listView.

  case 1:
    intent = new Intent(Activity.this,secondActivity.class);
    break;
 case 2:
    intent = new Intent(Activity.this,thirdActivity.class);
    break;
//add more if you have more items in listView
startActivity(intent);
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?>adapter,View v, int position){
    Intent intent;
    switch(position){
      case 0:
        intent = new Intent(Activity.this,firstActivity.class);
        break;
      case 1:
        intent = new Intent(Activity.this,secondActivity.class);
        break;
     case 2:
        intent = new Intent(Activity.this,thirdActivity.class);
        break;
    //add more if you have more items in listview
   //0 is the first item 1 second and so on...
    }
    startActivity(intent);
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to go around the whole thing by replacing the context reference from `this` or `Context.this` to `getapplicationcontext`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this in Activity itself, you do not create adapter.

```
ListView listView;
private List<> devicesList = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayAdapter<String> devicesAdapter;

listView = findViewById(R.id.devicesListView);
devicesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
devicesListView.setAdapter(devicesAdapter);
```

On click listener,

```
devicesListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position)+"";
                Toast.makeText(DeviceScanActivity.this, ""+item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```