# Android - How to make an Activity for each item in a ListView and pass Java Object to next screen

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a ListView of contacts and each contact is a Java object with a bunch of information associated with it. Some of that info is shown in the ListView, but the rest is meant for the DetailView. I'm trying to write a method that will take me to a DetailView for any contact I click on, but I also need to take the object with me. I store all of the contacts in an ArrayList in my MainActivity.java

My questions: Do I need to take the contact object with me or is there actually some way to access my ArrayList in another Activity?
If I can/have to take it with me, how would I do so, since the putExtra() methods don't take objects as arguments.

The beginning of my MainActivity looks like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

ListView list;
```

I have a very basic onClickListener right now but don't know what to put into it:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailView.class);
    intent.putExtra("contact", i);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

I feel like my initial definition of the MainActivity class doesn't correspond to the onItemClick method or something, which is why it doesn't execute and take me to another screen.

Comment: *An activity for each item??* You're going to be mad! If you have 50 items..I don't want to see the result. Choose `Fragment`s in your case: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html

Comment: I'm sorry, I may have not worded the question correctly due to being new at this. All I want is to click on each contact and go to a DetailView for it. The DetailView is already written and would just have its fields populated by the contact's information.

Comment: So you have ActivityA and ActivityB, you don't need to add others for each item? You reassure me :)

Comment: Yes, sorry that's what I meant. And ActivityB is just a template that gets filled in.

Comment: I see two answers below where they just pass a user id or id this is the way to go.  It's pretty difficult to pass a class with android and what you end up with is a copy of the class.  Here is an example of sending a class to an intent with android.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21295328/android-listview-with-onclick-items/21296055#21296055

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, DetailView.class);
intent.putExtra("extra_name","extra");
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in the other Activity :

```
/*onCreate*/
Object extra = getIntent().getExtra().get("extra_name");
```

I would recommend to pass an ID of some sort pointing to the description, passing complex data structure with intents is not recommended

Comment: How would I achieve the ID thing? Because you're right, if I attempt to write `intent.putExtra("contact", contacts.get(i));` it causes an error.

Comment: contacts is a complexe type (a class). Are we talking of a Android Contact or a custom class you created ? If you created the class, how do you identify each entry ? It could be the first name or email, doesn't really matters.

If you want to pass complex types, you will have to learn about Parcelable : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html

Comment: I figured it out, thanks. Now my problem is that clicking on a contact doesn't actually take me to a new screen for whatever reason.

Comment: Have you added the new activity to the manifest ? I then to forget to do that a lot xD

Comment: It was made automatically since I'm in Eclipse. Looks like this: `<activity
            android:name="com.example.contacts.DetailView"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_detail_view" >
        </activity>`

Is that missing anything?

Comment: Eddited my answer accordingly, it should appear. Do you have any Error message ? If a black screen appears, then you're just missing a layout.

Comment: Still doesn't even move to another screen. Just lights up and nothing happens. I think I may know where something is wrong, but not why. Could you take a look at my revised question in a second?

Comment: Nevermind I just got it! My code was in the wrong place! THANKS FOR YOUR HELP! You have no idea how much it means.

Answer (score 3):

Simply, use `Intent.putExtra()` to pass the information and `getIntent().getExtras()` to receive the information.

```
// call a new intent
myIntent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);  
// put an extra (like this following string)  
String userid = "User A";
myIntent.putExtra("TAG_CONTACT_ID", userid);  
startActivity(myIntent);

// receive the info in your onCreate method in ActivityB
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras != null) {
    String newUserID = extras.getString("TAG_CONTACT_ID");
}
```

See [this short example](http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam?recipeId=809) for more information.

If you want to pass an Integer, you can do it as the following: `myIntent.putExtra("value", i);` and take it with: `int myValue = extras.getInt("value");`.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
    int position, long id) {

    Contact c = (Contact)contacts.get(position);
    Intent i = new Intent();

    i.putExtras("contact", c);
    i.setClass(this, Activity2.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create java object with parcelable

Check the below code to create parcelable object in Android.

```
public class ObjFeedImages implements Parcelable {

    public int image_id;
    public boolean like_status = false;
    public String image_url = null;

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeStringArray(new String[] {
                String.valueOf(image_id),
                String.valueOf(like_status),
                image_url, });

    }

    public ObjFeedImages(Parcel in) {

        String[] data = new String[3];
        int i = 0;
        in.readStringArray(data);

        image_id = Integer.parseInt(data[i++]);//
        like_status = Boolean.parseBoolean(data[i++]);
        image_url = data[i++];

    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<ObjFeedImages> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<ObjFeedImages>() {
        @Override
        public ObjFeedImages createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            try {
                return new ObjFeedImages(source);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public ObjFeedImages[] newArray(int size) {
            try {
                return new ObjFeedImages[size];
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
    };

}
```

After creating some list of such object say

```
ObjFeedImages object = new ObjFeedImages();
object.image_id = 1;
object.like_status = true;
object.image_url="http://some image url";



Intent intent = new Intent(/*Your Intent Info*/);
intent.putExtras("key_name",object);
startActivity(intent);
```

[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20android.os.Parcelable%29) is the complete description.

To retrive object in other activity you have to write below code.

```
ObjFeedImages objectOnOtherActivity = (ObjFeedImages)getIntent().getParcelableExtra("key_name");
```

So ready to enjoy code.
Happy coding....