# How to make a clickable by item ListView that starts a new activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've been scouring youtube for hours and I cant seem to find one that works. So far I have this in my code but it wont let me start a new activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
ArrayList<PerMoney> PeepList = new ArrayList<PerMoney>();
int pos = -1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ListView people = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.peopleList);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if(PeepList.size() != 0)
        UpdateList();
    people.setOnItemClickListener(onListClick);
}
```

and then here is the onitemclick part

```
private AdapterView.OnClickListener onListClick=new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
{
        ListView people = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.peopleList);
        int res;
        people.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override

             public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
             {
                   pos = position;
                   Intent intent = new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
                   startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
             }
        };
}
```

Comment: duplicate, look here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21295328/android-listview-with-onclick-items

Comment: I'm trying this but its not letting use the same syntax, I dont understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't it be:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
```