# Why ListView onClick does not work?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listfragment

Trying to implement a onlick functionality for the android listview but something seems to not working. I tried to find some solutions over the internet and I found that there were recommendation to change the focusable property of imageview and textview elements. Tried it and it did not work. Appreciate if you guys can recommend any other alternatives.

Layout item.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/rootItemId"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable='false'
        android:background="@drawable/frame">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivIcon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:focusable='false'
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:focusable='false'
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ivIcon">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusable='false'
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

list fragment

```
    public class EventsListFragment extends ListFragment{

    ArrayList<Event> eventsChildren;
    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        Log.e("RedditListingsClick",position + " " + id);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        eventsChildren = new ArrayList<Event>();
        EventsChildAdapter adapter = new EventsChildAdapter(inflater.getContext(), eventsChildren);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

list adapter

```
public class EventsChildAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Event> {

    Context context;
    RelativeLayout root;
    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView title;
        ImageView thumbnail;
    }

    public EventsChildAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Event> eventsChildren) {
        super(context, R.layout.item_listing, eventsChildren);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Get the data item for this position
        Event child = getItem(position);

        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
           ViewHolder viewHolder; // view lookup cache stored in tag
           if (convertView == null) {
              viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
              LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
              convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_listing, null);
               //root=(RelativeLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.rootItemId);

               viewHolder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
               //viewHolder.thumbnail = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivIcon);

              convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
           } else {
               viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
           }
           // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
           System.out.println(child.getTitle());
           viewHolder.title.setText(child.getTitle());

            Picasso.with(this.context).load(child.getThumbnailImageURL()).resize(200, 100).into(viewHolder.thumbnail);

        // Return the completed view to render on screen
           return convertView;
    }
}
```

In addition to the above, I have already tried adding android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" to relativelayout but still did not work. Finally I tried to make the root relativelayout clickable and removed focus from the other elements and this did not work either.

Comment: are you getting the image in list view??

Comment: check this link   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21295328/android-listview-with-onclick-items

Comment: @DemoMail Yes I am getting the image in the listview.

Comment: Try convertView.setOnClickListener

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
public class EventsListFragment extends ListFragment implement OnItemClickListener {
 ...
    @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int    position,long id) {
  // the child callback here.
 }
}
```

and this in **onActivityCreated**

```
setListAdapter(Your adapter);
getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

Comment: Where do you want me to create onActivityCreated?
getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this); would give an error right? :)

Comment: if you using onCreateView, just do it in onCreateView()