# how to give onClick event to listview where the data is dynamically generated

Tags: android, listview

I am an android beginner.
I am trying to give **onClick event to the data in the listview**. The data is getting from the mysql database and storing in the sqlite and it was displaying on the screen. I am not getting any idea how to give onClick event for that data. Please give me suggestion.

Thanks in advance.

I am trying develop a time table app. When the user clicks on a button the classes he have to attend on that day have to be display in a listview. When he clicks on the class he have to get details of that class.

public class tuesday extends ListActivity  {

```
private ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
private String DATABASE_TABLE = SQLiteDB.DATABASE_TABLE;
private SQLiteDatabase newDB;
private static final String KEY_PERIODNO = "periodno";
private static final String KEY_PERIODNAME = "periodname";

private String id;
TextView periodno,periodname;


SQLiteDB sqlite_obj;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tuesday);

    sqlite_obj = new SQLiteDB(tuesday.this);
    Intent previous = getIntent();
    id = previous.getStringExtra("id");
    Log.i("id: ", " " + id);

    select_seqlite();


}


private void select_seqlite() {

    sqlite_obj.open();

    Cursor c = sqlite_obj.gettuesdayData();
    if (c.moveToFirst())
    {
        do {
            DisplayContact(c);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }

    sqlite_obj.close();
}




private void DisplayContact(Cursor c) {


    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
            "\n" +"periodno: " + c.getString(2)+ "\n"+"periodname: " + c.getString(3)+ "\n", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    TextView tview = new TextView(this);
    tview.setText("      "  + c.getString(2)  +
            " "+ c.getString(3));
    getListView().addHeaderView(tview);

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.activity_list_item,results));

    getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);}}
```

Comment: Share your code of adapter class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android ListView with onClick items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21295328/android-listview-with-onclick-items)

Answer (score 0):

In your activity, where you defined your listview

write this below code

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){   
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?>adapter,View v, int position){
        ItemClicked item = adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);

        Intent intent = new Intent(Activity.this,destinationActivity.class);
        //based on item add info to intent
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

And In your adapter's getItem you write

```
public ItemClicked getItem(int position){
    return items.get(position);
}
```

I hope it might help you!