# Android: OnClick listener on a button in a listview populated with an adapter

Tags: android, listview

So I have a `ListView` that is populated from an `ArrayList<>` of an object via a custom adapter.

Each row in the `ListView` is a horizontal layout that contains a `TextView` widget and a Button widget. There can be between `0` and `2` rows in this `ListView`.

I want to be able to have an `onClick` method on the `Button` which allows me to pass to the method in the `onClick` the position of the `Button` clicked in the list (i.e. was it in the 1st or 2nd row?)

This is the `XML` of the page with the `ListView` (the button listed here is irrelevant for this question)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:text="Saved Offer Leaflets"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="30dp"/>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewPdfs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:text="Check for latest offers"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/buttonCheckLatestOffers"
    />
```

This is my list item for the adapter

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:text="date" />

<Button
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/buttonOpenPdf"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="Open"
     />
  </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You haven't really asked a question- could you update your question? Also, add your java code. I'm not sure what way you're doing this, but the viewholder pattern could be useful to you if you haven't looked that up yet

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android ListView with onClick items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21295328/android-listview-with-onclick-items)

Comment: There are so many duplicates of this question that I spent more time chosing one of them than reading the post..

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately if you're needing the position of an item. It's not recommended to put the `onClick` functionality within the `XML` but rather declare it within the `Activity` where you're setting the adapter to your `ListView`.

A generic example would be:

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){   
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?>adapter,View v, int position){
        ItemClicked item = adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);
        //Logic for click of ItemView
    }
});
```

So for a case such as yours, you'll need to determine if the click instance is on top of your button, so to apply the logic correct you'll need to use a `Switch` statement to determine if your `Button` has been selected inside the `onItemClickListener`.

So, it would look something like this:

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){   
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?>adapter,View v, int position){
            ItemClicked item = adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);
            switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.buttonid: 
             //button click logic here
                 break;

             }
    });
```

**Note**: make sure your `getItem` function in your adapter works sufficiently.

```
public ItemClicked getItem(int position){
    return arraylist.get(position);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A small example case:

```
int selectedItemPos = -1;

public void initUI(){
    ListView myListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewPdfs);
    myListView.setAdapter(/*provide the data to the adapter*/);
    myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adpterView, View view, 
                                int position, long id) {
                    selectedItemPos = position;
            }
    });

    [...]
    myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (selectedItemPos != -1){
                    //selectedItemPos = 0 means first row of listview 
                    //has been selected and so on, do what you want with it
                }
            }
    });
}
```

BTW as said by others it's plenty of duplicates out there.