# arraylist inside arraylist in android

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I want to put one arrayList inside another arrayList, but I have some problems with that.

Basicly this is what I want:

```
ArrayList<ObjectThatContainArraylist> myList1;
ArrayList<ObjectThatContain3Strings> myList2;
```

I want `myList2` few times as an objects inside `myList1`, so when I get`(position)` of `mylist1`, I will get in each `get(position)` a different arraylist with 3 different strings.

So that I have 2 `listviews` in my `mainActivity`, the first `listview` is supposed to show the indexes of `myList1` and it does. When clicking on one of its items it send the position from `onSetItemListener` to the adapter of the second `listview`, in which the `listview` is supposed to show `myList2` with 3 Strings in each item/index of the `listview`, but it only shows one index instead of all the indexes I added earlier.

### Question

Is the method I used here correct? Is it the right and easiest way to get an arraylist of objects (with 3 Strings in it) inside an arraylist which needs to hold few of those arraylists with objects inside them (see image below)?

Edit:

This is what I am trying to do:

[image: What I am trying to do]

This is my adapter:

```
public class AdapterForSecondListView extends BaseAdapter {
    ArrayList myList = new ArrayList();
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    int positionClickedInParentArray;

@Override
public ArrayList<ObjectParcelable> getItem(int position) {
    return (ArrayList<ObjectParcelable>) myList.get(position);
}

public AdapterForChildListView(Context context, ArrayList myList, int positionClickedInParentArray) {
    this.context = context;
    this.myList = myList;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.positionClickedInParentArray = positionClickedInParentArray;
}

@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final MyViewHolder mViewHolder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate (R.layout.items_for _second_listview, parent, false);

            mViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
        } else {
            mViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        final ArrayList<ObjectParcelable> currentListData = getItem(positionClickedInParentArray);

        if (position<currentListData.size()) {
            mViewHolder.firstTitle.setText(currentListData.get(position).getFirstTitle());
mViewHolder.secondTitle.setText(currentListData.get(position).getSecondTitle());
mViewHolder.description.setText(currentListData.get(position).getDescription());

        }
        return convertView;
    }

private class MyViewHolder {
        TextView firstTitle;
        TextView secondTitle;
        TextView description;

        public MyViewHolder(View item) {
            firstTitle = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.firstTitleOfChildArray);
            secondTitle = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.secondTitleOfChildArray);
            description = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.descriptionOfChildArray);
        }

    }

}


// this is the method that supposed to add the object to the position, 
// it gets both the object and the position from mainActivity
// in the logs i printed the size of the second position, and when running
// in the emulator i tried to add only to the first position, 
// and it add to the both of them 

public void getDataInListForSecondListView(Context context, ObjectParcelable objectParcelable, int position) {
        Log.d("Tab5", "Before : ParentList.get(1).size() = " + String.valueOf(parentList.get(1).size()));
        parentList.get(position).add(objectParcelable);
        Log.d("Tab5", "After : ParentList.get(1).size() = " + String.valueOf(parentList.get(1).size()));
    }
```

Comment: please add some code

Comment: So you want to have a multilevel listview?

Comment: your question not clear but .. You can use List<List<YourObject>> list =new ArrayList();

Comment: Consider using separate class for this kind of complex data structure. Nested ArrayList() will hurt readability

Comment: Stefan, thank you for your answer.

Comment: i just wonder how can i add another object to the inside list, how can i call position = 2 of the outside list and add an object of Strings to that list?

Answer (score 4):

Find the solution

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> mainArrayList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
ArrayList<String> subArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
mainArrayList.add(subArrayList );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create `List<List<YourModelClass>> list = new ArrayList();`

Comment: this should be a comment.

Comment: Pallavi, thank you for your answer. i'm just wondering how can i add another object to the inside list, i mean: how can i call position = 2 of the outside list and add to that list an object of Strings?

Answer (score 0):

@shon to retrieve or update inside list then you need to assign inside list to new list and made changes to new assigned list and update to the inside list based on outside list position.

Answer (score 0):

To create such a list you can do it like this:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> parentlist = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

If you want to add a new child list to that parent list do it like that:

```
ArrayList<String> childlist = new ArrayList<String>();
childlist.add("a");
childlist.add("b");
childlist.add("c");

// add the childlist to the parent list
parentlist.add(childlist);
```

To add strings to a list of a specific position you can do this:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> parentlist = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

// get the childlist on position 2
ArrayList<String> childlist = parentlist.get(2);

// if childlist is not null the list already exist and you can add your strings
// otherwise you have to create a new list and add it to your parent list
if(childlist != null) {
  childlist.add("a");
  childlist.add("b");
  childlist.add("c");
}
else {
  childlist = new ArrayList<String>();
  childlist.add("a");
  childlist.add("b");
  childlist.add("c");

  // add the new childlist to the parent list because it didn't exist
  parentlist.add(childlist);
}
```

**UPDATE**

I assume you have fragment/activity a with listview1. You click on an item of listview1 and open a new fragment/activity which includes listview2. Now you have to pass the data to that new fragment/activity.

The adapter of listview2 could look like this:

```
public class ObjectParcelableAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ObjectParcelable> {
  public ObjectParcelableAdapter (Context context, ArrayList<ObjectParcelable> objects) {
    super(context, 0, objects);
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Get the data item for this position
    ObjectParcelable object = getItem(position);    

    // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    if (convertView == null) {
      convertView =LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.items_for _second_listview, parent, false);
    }

    // set your textviews values here
    return convertView;
  }
}
```

And this is the way you create the adapter:

```
// Create the adapter to convert the array to views
UsersAdapter adapter = new ObjectParcelableAdapter(this, listofobjects);

// Attach the adapter to a ListView
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview2);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And if you create the new fragment/activity for listview2 you have to pass the list of objects you want to show in listview2. For that you have to implement an onclicklistener. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21295576/6632568) for an example.

Comment: Thank you very much, i think this is  my solution, i just need to know how to use it in the adapter of the list view, in order to show the Strings in their places. oh and btw, i don't use the 3 Strings saperate, i use them in a custom object because every childList has few sets of 3 Strings...

Comment: If i understand what you want you have to do it like this: `parentlist.get(position).getStrings();` (you get the custom object of a specific position and get the strings from the custom object). That's the way you have to use it in your adapter. Without code of your adapter i can't help you more...

Comment: i added my adapter, my adapter seems correct but it doesn't work... :/

Comment: I used your solution, and I am using this to add my object to the child list parentList.get(position).add(ObjectParcelable); (position equels the location i want to add the object to)  but this is adding the same object to all the positions of the parent list instead to just the specific position i told it to, any idea why this is doing that? btw i tried putting logs to track on the sizes, and even though I am not asking it to add the object to any other position it still add the same object to all the positions..

Comment: Where do you call the add function?

Comment: In the fragment, in a dedicated method I made, it gets the object I want to add and the position of the parentList I want to add it to. I even tracked the size of the parentList in position 0 and tried adding only to ParentList in position 1, and it still adds the object to both positions, i tracked this size using both logs and running on the debbuger and I am 99% sure the problem is somehow in this line of code:  `  
    parentList.get(position).add(objectParcelable);
 `  because this is the spot where the size of position 0 also gets the object even i didn't tell it to...

Comment: I also think that the problem is there where you're trying to add your object to the list. Can you update your question with the code where you call this add?

Comment: I edited my question and added the code where i add the object

Comment: Please add the code where you call `getDataInListForSecondListView()` that we can see were the param `position` is coming from.

Comment: I let the user choose the position by starting different activity that has ListView using startActivityForResult() in my MainActivity, and when the user clicks on one of the items in the listView in that acticity then that activity finishes and sends back (the position that the user clicked on) to the OnActivityResult() method in MainActicity which then calls the getDataInListForSecondListView() in my 5th fragment of the MainActivity. And btw don't worry I only call the getDataInListForSecondListView() once, I already checked that with the debbuger...

Comment: I can't help you without seeing the code... You should debug the whole process, check input params and where you add objects to the lists. Maybe there is a problem with the arraylist you get with `parentlist.get(position)` because you say you only add an object to pos 0 and you also get this object on pos 1. Maybe there is the same list on both positions. Take care that you always create a new list for every childlist of parentlist.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! my mistake was that I put the "ArrayList<ObjectParcelable> childList = new ArrayList<ObjectParcelable>();"  in the beginning before onAttach, and everytime just used "chilList.clean();" to clean it before adding new objects to it, then I removed the "clean" call and moved the "ArrayList<ObjectParcelable> childList = new ArrayList<>();" to the inside of getDataInList and it is now working as expected, thank you so much!! :)